Consume File based on Thread number produced by previous thread Group
My create artifact scenario is creating file as
../Data/CreateArtifactObjectId_Thread_1.txt
../Data/CreateArtifactObjectId_Thread_2.txt
../Data/CreateArtifactObjectId_Thread_3.txt
File Format:  ../Data/CreateArtifactObjectId_Thread_${__threadNum}.txt
When I run the delete Thread,
For Thread 1 (which is User 1 Thread) should read artifact ID from ../Data/CreateArtifactObjectId_Thread_1.txt
For Thread 2 (which is User 2 Thread) should read artifact ID from ../Data/CreateArtifactObjectId_Thread_2.txt
For Thread 3 (which is User 3 Thread) should read artifact ID from ../Data/CreateArtifactObjectId_Thread_3.txt
In User Defined Variable - I've defined
file as ../Data/CreateArtifactObjectId_Thread_${__threadNum}.txt but it's not working.

As per User Defined Variables documentation:

The User Defined Variables element lets you define an initial set of variables, just as in the Test Plan.
Note that all the UDV elements in a test plan - no matter where they are - are processed at the start.

More information: Using User Defined Variables
So you will get the file path for a single user, if you want to read the data dynamically from the file - go for i.e. __StringFromFile() function like:
${__StringFromFile(../Data/CreateArtifactObjectId_Thread_${__threadNum}.txt,,,)}


I am getting this error -I can confirm file is there

It picks up the file and read the first line and then it try to find file for that value.
2024-07-23 10:22:37,133 INFO o.a.j.f.StringFromFile: DeleteArtifact 3-1 opening file ../Data/CreateArtifactObjectId_Thread_1.txt
5.6.3/Data/CreateFolderObjectId.txt@1701895620
2024-07-23 10:22:37,135 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: 016ffea6-ae0a-45a6-b6b4-a3824c2aa469
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File 016ffea6-ae0a-45a6-b6b4-a3824c2aa469 must exist and be readable
